# Stop tweepy from needing to open, append, and close a file for every new tweet

Tags: python, csv, twitter, tweepy

Here is a short piece of code I have been working on. It saves tweets using tweepy. My problem is that every time a new tweet comes in, the code has to open the csv, append the text, and then close the csv again... only to open the file again milliseconds later for the next tweet. This feels super inefficient. How can I improve this?

```
class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def __init__(self, api = None):
        self.api = api
        csvFile = open('tweets.csv', 'w')

    def on_status(self, status): 

        csvFile = open(tweets.csv, 'a')
        csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)
        csvWriter.writerow([status.text])
        csvFile.close()

        return
```